# How to get DISINCT values of one column from a join query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, distinct

I am having a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_1.id_1,
    table_1.id_2,
    table_1_id_3
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id_1 = table_2.id_1
        AND table_1.id_2 = table_2.id_2
INNER JOIN table_3
    ON table_2.id_1 = table_3.id_2
        AND table_2.id_2 = table_3.id_2
WHERE table_2.code = 'Y'
    AND table_2.site = 'N'
    AND table_3.code = 'Q'
```

This gives me distinct combination of id_1, id_2 and id_3 satisfying the conditions. How should the query be to get distinct values of only id_1 matching all the conditions.

I am not posting the table contents as they are having large number of columns and as this question is a query specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the second and third fields from the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    table_1.id_1    
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id_1 = table_2.id_1
        AND table_1.id_2 = table_2.id_2
INNER JOIN table_3
    ON table_2.id_1 = table_3.id_2
        AND table_2.id_2 = table_3.id_2
WHERE table_2.code = 'Y'
    AND table_2.site = 'N'
    AND table_3.code = 'Q'
```

Comment: When I remove the second and third fields, i am getting an error message stating 'Error code: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Comment: I assume this is part of an INSERT query then? Remove columns 2 and 3 from the insert as well. Know that the values will be NULL for columns 2 and 3 though.

Comment: Keep your query as your inner query and write select distict id_1(..your query..);

Comment: @JNevill Yes!!, it was part of an insert query , I forgot to comment the insert statement first!.. Don't know how I missed that. Thank you.